# What is the correct date(conversion) for DB2 v 6.x using open query in ms sql server 2012 over an i5 ODBC driver?

Tags: sql-server, db2, openquery

I am attempting to extract data from IBM's System i ODBC driver for i5;DB2 version 6.x using open query from mssql2012. The query is using a date range predicate: *where date(rhinvdt) between date('01/01/12')* and date('01/31/14')* . This causes the return message:

**"[IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0181 - Value in date, time, or timestamp string not valid.**".

When I executed the exact same query (cut and paste) in IBM Data Studio, the query succeeds, returning the expected data. I realize IBM Data Studio is using jdbc vs. mssql2012 open query over a linked server connection,however, I don't understand enough about date conversion functions on the iseries side to know if a better alternative for the
conversion should be used for openquery. BTW, I print out the sql, so I can see if I have the syntax correct. That is what I was able to cut and paste from the mssql2012 message output to execute via IBM Data Studio as is to get the result set. I also executed the statement: *select current date from sysibm.sysdummy1;* from IBM Data Studio to get the default date setting, which returned:  **02/05/14**

Here's the code

```
    DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(4000)
    SET @sql = 'SELECT rhvendno, 
          rhvennam, 
          rhinvno, 
          rhinvdt
        FROM metrodev.rsphdr
        WHERE date(rhinvdt) between date(''' + '01/01/12' + ''') and date(''' + '01/31/14' + ''')
         FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY'

    print @sql
    exec(@sql) at ISERIES;
```

Here are the results from *print @sql:*

```
     SELECT rhvendno, 
          rhvennam, 
          rhinvno, 
          rhinvdt
        FROM metrodev.rsphdr
        WHERE date(rhinvdt) between date('01/01/12') and date('01/31/14')
         FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 1):

Try supplying the date values in the ISO format: `'2012-01-01'`. What is the data type of `rhinvdt`? If it is DATE, you don't need to use the `date()` function as DB2 will implicitly cast character values to the DATE type.

By the way, it's not z/OS you're connecting to:

> [System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]

Comment: Thanks mustaccio-- rhinvdt is defined as char(8). The data looks like 01/01/14. The yyyy-mm-dd format yields the same results. I cleared up the "connecting to" info in the original question.

Comment: In that case it is possible that the table contains one or more values that do not represent valid dates. It is also possible that the default date format, [described in the manual](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzdatestrings.htm), is not set to `MM/DD/YY` as you expect. As an aside, if people quit storing datetime values as strings, the world would be a much happier place.

Comment: >>if people quit storing datetime values as strings, the world would be a much happier place<<  --ain't it the truth!! :) Good call on checking the validity of the data stored under rhinvdt, i'll call that column back over the IBM Data studio connection first to see what I get.

Comment: It looks like rhinvdt converts under IBM Data Studio without incident, however, under the mssql2012/odbc/linked server open query context, the statement: select date(rhinvdt) from metrodev.rsphdr executes without error-but-- dubs the result set values for all as NULL.

Comment: Data Studio uses JDBC, hence the difference. I'm not very familiar with System i -- check the manual linked above on how to configure the default date format.